# Concatenating and appending to a DataFrame inside the For Loop in Python

Tags: python, pandas, for-loop, concatenation, cluster-analysis

I have the following problem.

There is quite big dataset with the features and IDs. Due to the task definition, I'm trying to do clustering but not for all dataset, instead of that I'm taking each of the IDs and then train the model on the feature data from this particular ID. How does that look in details:

Imagine, that we have our initial dataframe `df_init`

Then I create the array with unique ID_s:

```
dd = df_init['ID'].unique()
```

After that, set comprehension is being created just like that:

```
dds = {x:y for x,y in df_init.groupby('ID')}
```

Using for loops and iterating over `dds`, I'm taking the data and use it for training the clustering algorithm. After that, `pd.concat()` is using to get the dataframe back(for this example, will show only two IDs):

```
df = pd.DataFrame()
d={}
n=5

for i in dd[:2]:
    d[i] = dds[i].iloc[: , 1:5].values   
    ac = AgglomerativeClustering(n_clusters=n, linkage='complete').fit(d[i])
    labels = ac.labels_
    labels = pd.DataFrame(labels)
    df = pd.concat([df, labels])
    print(i)
    print('Labels: ', labels)
```

So the result for this loop will be following output:

[image]

And the output df will look like that(shown only for first ID, the rest labels are also there):

[image]

My question is the following: how can I add the additional column to this dataframe in the loop, that will be matching certain ID to corresponding labels (4 labels-ID_1, another 4 labels-ID_2, etc.)? Are there any pandas solution for achieving that?

[image]

Many thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

Below this line:

```
labels = pd.DataFrame(labels)
```

Add the following:

```
labels['ID']=i
```

This will give you the extra column with the proper ID for each subset